Study the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 \cos^2 (x)}dx$
The function $e^{-x^2 \cos^2 (x)}$ is positive and continuous on $ [0,\infty)$. We know that:
$0≤\cos^2(x)≤1, \forall x$
$\Rightarrow -x^2≤-x^2\cos^2(x)≤0$
$\Rightarrow e^{-x^2}≤e^{-x^2\cos^2(x)}≤1. $
The gaussian integral is convergent, but I don't know how to find an upper bound in order to assure the main integral convergence.
Thanks for your help.

I don't think the integral converges. For large $x$, the integrand consists of a series of "spikes" at $x_k = \pi\left(\frac{1}{2} + k\right)$ for integer $k$. The area under spike $k$ is approximately $2/[(1+2k)\sqrt{\pi}]$. The sum over the areas under all of the spikes therefore does not converge.

Let $ N $ be an arbitrary positive integer. For each $ 0 \leq k \leq N $, let $ 0 <\delta_k \leq 1 $, with its specific value to be chosen appropriately later. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ \pi (N + 1)} \! \!{\rm e}^{ - x^2 \cos ^2 x} {\rm d}x \ge \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1)}^{\frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1) + \delta _k } {{\rm e}^{ - x^2 \cos ^2 x} {\rm d}x} } & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\int_0^{\delta _k } {{\rm e}^{ - \left( {x + \frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1)} \right)^2 \sin ^2 x} {\rm d}x} } \\ & \ge \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\delta _k {\rm e}^{ - \left( {\delta _k  + \frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1)} \right)^2 \sin ^2 \delta _k } } .
\end{align*}
Choosing $ \delta_k = \frac{1}{k+1} $ and utilising the inequality $ \sin x \leq x $ for any real $ x $, we deduce
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ \pi (N + 1) } \!\!{\rm e}^{ - x^2 \cos ^2 x} {\rm d}x  & \ge \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}{\rm e}^{ - \left( {\frac{1}{{k + 1}} + \frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1)} \right)^2 \sin ^2 \left( {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}} \right)} }  \ge \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}{\rm e}^{ - \left( {\frac{1}{{k + 1}} + \frac{\pi }{2}(2k + 1)} \right)^2 \frac{1}{{(k + 1)^2 }}} } \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}{\rm e}^{ - \left( {\frac{1}{{(k + 1)^2 }} + \frac{\pi }{2}\frac{{2k + 1}}{{k + 1}}} \right)^2 } }  \ge {\rm e}^{ - (1 + \pi )^2 } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}} 
\end{align*}
Now, letting $ N \to +\infty $ and appealing to the fact that the harmonic series diverges, we conclude that the improper integral is divergent.

Thanks a lot for this splendid solution. Does the integral in question can help us in determining the nature of the series of the following general term:
$a_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-n^2\pi^2\cos^2 t-2n\pi t}dt, n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$a_n  = {\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } \int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\exp ( - n^2 \pi ^2 \sin ^2 t - 2n\pi t){\rm d}t}  \sim {\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } \int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\exp ( - n^2 \pi ^2 t^2  - 2n\pi t){\rm d}t} \ = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } }}{n}\int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}n}^{\frac{\pi }{2}n} {\exp ( - \pi ^2 t^2  - 2\pi t){\rm d}t}  \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } }}{n}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - \pi ^2 t^2  - 2\pi t){\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\rm e}}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } }}{n}
$$

Or $$
a_n  = {\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } \int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\exp ( - n^2 \pi ^2 \sin ^2 t - 2n\pi t){\rm d}t}  = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n\pi ^2 } }}{n}\int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}n}^{\frac{\pi }{2}n} {\exp \left( { - \pi ^2 t^2 \left( {\frac{{\sin (t/n)}}{{t/n}}} \right)^2  - 2\pi t} \right){\rm d}t} ,
$$ and by dominated convergence $$
\int_{-\frac{\pi }{2}n}^{\frac{\pi }{2}n} {\exp \left( { - \pi ^2 t^2 \left( {\frac{{\sin (t/n)}}{{t/n}}}\right)^2-2\pi t} \right){\rm d}t}\to\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - \pi ^2 t^2  - 2\pi t){\rm d}t}  = \frac{{\rm e}}{{\sqrt \pi}}.
$$

If I answered your original question, you may accept it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Thank you sir very much for your time and help.

I see that several of your questions have been answered on this site but you have never accepted any of them. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers By accepting I do not simply mean you say thank you, you can click on the check mark on the left of the answer.
